# How to show that this set is a sigma algebra

Tags: math, set, algebra

I am studying "FAMILIES OF SETS" in the book "Real analysis for graduate
students(v 3.1)" by Richard F. Bass and I could not figure out this example.

[The example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siIzL.png)

[Definition of an algebra and sigma-algebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYO42.png)

They are stating that

> Verifying parts (1) and (2) of the definition is easy.

This is exactly the part I do not understand.
I do not understand how we define the complement for a set {0,1,2}. The set {0,1,2} should be in D, as it is countable, but what is its complement? It seems that it is {...,-3-2-1} union {3,4,5,...}. Are these sets both countable?

And what about the set {1.1, 2.5, 3.4}, how do we define the complement of such a set? (and how do we show that it is in fact in D?)

P.S.
I do not know how to write formulas so I'm sorry for the ugly mathematical writing

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions, you probably want to ask this on the sister site http://math.stackexchange.com instead.  That site also supports proper math formula formatting, see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complement of {0,1,2} in R is every real number except those three. It's also in the algebra because that was the definition, you defined an algebra of all countable subsets or the complements of countable subsets.